# Is an lvalue reference returned from a function actually an rvalue (from the perspective of the caller)?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue, lvalue

How is it possible to have an lvalue reference refer to an lvalue reference returned from a function? Isn't the lvalue reference returned from that function actually an rvalue from the perspective of the caller? For example:

```
class Obj {};

Obj& refToRef(Obj& o) {
    return o;
}

int main() {
    Obj o;
    Obj& o2 = refToRef(o);
}
```

How is `o2` (an lvalue reference) able to refer to what appears to be an rvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind two properties when thinking about value-ness of an expression, identity and move-ability. An expression has identity if it has a name or an address, and is moveable if it's going to expire once the expression has been evaluated.

- Lvalue = has identity and is not moveable
- Xvalue = has identity and
  is moveable
- Rvalue = does not have identity and is moveable

refToRef returns by lvalue reference, therefore the `Obj` that `refToRef(o)` refers to is an object with identity (`&refToRef(o)` is defined) and will still be around after the expression has been evaluated. `refToRef(o)` is therefore an lvalue.

Furthermore, be careful not to confuse type with valueness. If I add a function that returns by value and create an rvalue reference from it, the rvalue reference will be an lvalue. For example

```
class Obj {};
Obj& refToRef(Obj& o) {
    return o;
}

Obj refToVal(Obj& o) {
    return o;
}
int main() {
    Obj o;
    Obj& o2 = refToRef(o);
    Obj&& o3 = refToVal(o);
}
```

`o3` has type `rvalue refernce to Obj`, and as an expression is an `lvalue`.

Answer (score 8):

> Isn't the lvalue reference returned from that function actually an rvalue from the perspective of the caller?

No, because the result of a function call isn't *always* an rvalue.

From [[expr.call]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#14) (emphasis mine):

> **A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type** or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

I'm pretty sure this rule exists specifically to avoid the problem that your question is asking about.

Comment: Good counter-example to how most descriptions of value categories are extremely simplified.